# Unable to target div with JS

Tags: php, javascript, html, target, capture

I am trying to target a div nested within some php with js, but no matter what I do, I can't seem to target it. Here is the code for reference:
php:

```
echo "<li>"."<div id=\"countryclick\">". "<a href=\"?Continent=$Continent&Country=$Country\">" . $Country . " ". "</a>" . "</div>"."</li>";
```

js:

```
$("#countryclick").click(function(){
    $("#country").hide();
    $("#city").show();
});
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: try nest your js inside $(document).ready();

Comment: there's actually some js that i didn't include which has the $(document).ready();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div#countryclick
```

is created on the fly so you can use [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) of jQuery. 
Like:

```
$("#countryclick").live("click",function(){
   //code here
})
```

Comment: Zhujy is right here that may be your answer if you create div on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are creating div dynamically or not. If you are creating it dynamically you have to use live method as follows:

```
$("#countryclick").live("click",function(){
    $("#country").hide();
    $("#city").show();
});
```

Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li>
    <div id="countryclick">
      <a href="?Continent=<?php echo $Continent; ?>&Country=<?php echo $Country; ?>">
        LINK HERE
      </a>
    </div>
</li>
<div id="country">country</div>
<div id="city">city</div>

$("div#countryclick").live("click",function(){
    $("#country").hide();
    $("#city").show();
});
```

this should be working.

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. If you are using some older versions of jQuery you should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

[Visit here live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and [Here on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)